# C++: How to properly go through vector pointed to

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, vector, dereference

Say that I have a vector, *v*,

```
vector <int> v = {0,1,2,...n};
```

What is the proper way to loop through *v* in a function taking a pointer to *v* as an argument? I can see two ways, either dereference the vector using (*) or using the .at() member:

```
void foo(vector <int>* v)
{
    for (auto& el : (*v))
        bar(el);
}
```

or

```
void foo(vector <int>* v)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        bar(v->at(k));
}
```

Is there any difference between the two? Or is there another, superior, way to do it? It seems to me the second one would dereference the full vector object each iteration to get a single value, which seems like a bit of an over-kill, surely it would be better to only dereference the value at the memory location you want?

Comment: Have you considered using `void foo(std::vector<int> &v)` instead?

Comment: This is at least c++11, isn't it?

Comment: If you are going to change the vector then pass by reference, if not then pass by reference to const.

Comment: @Yunnosch Must be if he's trying to use `auto` with that loop syntax.

Comment: @nwp, nope, I had not, did not know it existed, see below. Yunnosch, yepp, it is. Ron, that's a good suggestion, I never did realize you could interchange between the two in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer will be dereferenced in both cases. However `at` performs range checking and throws an exception if it fails so second approach will be slower.

A proper approach may look like this:

```
void foo(::std::vector<int> & v)
{
    for(auto & el: v)
    {
        bar(el);
    }
}
```

Since your code assumes that pointer is always valid there is not a single reason to use it instead of a reference. [See Cpp Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-ptr-ref).

Comment: Ok, I had the idea that dereferencing the full vector was unnecessary, when one could only dereference one element with `at`. But I was misinformed about how dereferencing works. I also didn't know you could go: `::std::vector<int> & v` to pass a reference, I thought you did: `std::vector<int>* v`. The more you know.